# Cartographer ROS ignores NavSatFix

Tags: ros2, gps, cartographer

We are trying to improve mapping over large indoor areas with UWB positioning. We have a pose from the UWB system and convert it to GPS coordinates, and input it into the cartographer_node.

This is a sample message from the converted GPS message.

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 6002
    nanosec: 293000000
  frame_id: base_link
status:
  status: 0
  service: 0
latitude: 47.497893645426466
longitude: 19.04016638474693
altitude: 0.0
position_covariance:
- 1.771856807817194e-11
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 8.087793508722446e-12
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
position_covariance_type: 1
```

The problem is that cartographer seemingly ignores the message. We have set `use_nav_sat = true`, and carto complains when this data is not published. But when it is published, it disregards it. We know that by publishing obviously wrong fix data, like all zeros, and the map doesn't change (it should become worse).